# How can I handle ArrayIndexOutofBoundsException?

Tags: java, arrays, indexoutofboundsexception

The given part of the code gives me an `ArrayIndexOutofBoundsException`, but I don't actually know how to handle it.

```
int count = 0;
int n = sc.nextInt();
int[] a = new int[n];
for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    a[i] = sc.nextInt();
}
for(int i=1; i<n; i++)
{
    if(a[i+2]>a[i+8] && a[i+3]>a[i+8] && a[i+4]>a[i+8])
    {
        count++;
    }
}
System.out.println(count);
```

The array should stop working when it reaches `a[n-1]` but it goes beyond that in the for loop and gives me the out of bounds error.

Comment: if array size is `10`, when `i=9`, `i+8 = 17` --> a[17] ?? What do you anticipate?

Comment: You are using i+8 without knowing wether the arrays length is bigger or equal to 8. Change the second i<n to i<n+8

Comment: OOBE is an unchecked exception. Unchecked exceptions indicate that your code is wrong. Don't handle them; fix your code.